# Trouble using Javascript countdown timer and PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So, apparently and unfortunately you can't create a resfreshing non-static countdown timer using PHP only since it is a server-side language, so after a few digging I found a Javascript script that could do it.

However, the targeted date is a variable I get from a database and is stored in a PHP variable. What I am trying to do is use that variable as the target date on the javascript, but I am being unsuccessful.

```
<?php echo "You are currently looting a " . "<b>" . $lootinglocation . "</b> | <b> Time remaining: </b>
        <script language='JavaScript'>
            TargetDate = '" . $javatime . "';
            BackColor = 'palegreen';
            ForeColor = 'navy';
            CountActive = true;
            CountStepper = -1;
            LeadingZero = true;
            DisplayFormat = '%%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.';
        </script>
        <script language='JavaScript'   src='//scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js'></script>'";
?>
```

Things to consider:

- Here's the declaration of $java time: `

  ```
  $targettime = $dbtime; //This $dbtime is obtained trough a select query.

  $currenttime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

  $timeremaining = $targettime - $currenttime;

  $addedtime = "+" . $timeremaining . " seconds";

  $javatime = date("m/d/Y h:i:s A", strtotime($addedtime));`
  ```

Comment: I think it would benefit you both now and in the future to use Ajax to send this data, its incredibly simple and easy to pickup. It would allow you to send any variable to PHP for processing and return it to Javascript to handle the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the http: in the script.

```
<script language='JavaScript' src='http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js'></script>'";
```